# pony.orm.core.ERDiagramError: Inconsistent reverse attribute

Tags: python, orm, pony, ponyorm

I am getting this error when specifying my tables on Pony ORM.

```
  File "business.py", line 79, in <module>
    db.generate_mapping()
  File "<string>", line 2, in generate_mapping
  File "/home/ancinedev/.pyenv/versions/3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pony/utils/utils.py", line 58, in cut_traceback
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ancinedev/.pyenv/versions/3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 724, in generate_mapping
    entity._link_reverse_attrs_()
  File "/home/ancinedev/.pyenv/versions/3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 3511, in _link_reverse_attrs_
    throw(ERDiagramError, 'Inconsistent reverse attributes %s and %s' % (attr, attr2))
  File "/home/ancinedev/.pyenv/versions/3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pony/utils/utils.py", line 96, in throw
    raise exc
pony.orm.core.ERDiagramError: Inconsistent reverse attributes Pais.pessoas and Pessoa.identificador
```

My Pessoa table has an attribute called CD_PAIS and this attribute is a reference to Pais table, where it is set as a Primary Key.

```
class Pais(db.Entity):
    _table_ = ['SAD', 'TA_PAIS']
    codigo = PrimaryKey(int, column="CD_PAIS")
    nome = Required(str, column="NM_PAIS")
    pessoas = Set(lambda: Pessoa, reverse="identificador")

class Pessoa(db.Entity):
    _table_ = ['SAD', 'TB_PESSOA']
    identificador = PrimaryKey(int, column="ID_PESSOA")
    nome = Required(str, column="NM_PESSOA")
    tipo_pessoa = Required(str, column="IN_TIPO_PESSOA")
    numero_registro = Optional(str, column="NR_REGISTRO")
    pais = Required(Pais, reverse="codigo")
```

I tried many documentations and ways but was not success on that.

Thanks everyone for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code snippet is that you mistakenly point the `reverse` attribute to the primary key of another entity. First of all, the reverse attribute should be the relationship attribute of another entity, not its primary key. So for the `pessoas` attribute in `Pais` entity it should be the `pais` attribute in the `Pessoa` entity:

```
class Pais(db.Entity):
    _table_ = ['SAD', 'TA_PAIS']
    codigo = PrimaryKey(int, column="CD_PAIS")
    nome = Required(str, column="NM_PAIS")
    pessoas = Set(lambda: Pessoa, reverse="pais")

class Pessoa(db.Entity):
    _table_ = ['SAD', 'TB_PESSOA']
    identificador = PrimaryKey(int, column="ID_PESSOA")
    nome = Required(str, column="NM_PESSOA")
    tipo_pessoa = Required(str, column="IN_TIPO_PESSOA")
    numero_registro = Optional(str, column="NR_REGISTRO")
    pais = Required(Pais, reverse="pessoas")
```

But in this example specifying the `reverse` attribute is not necessary, because Pony can figure out the relationship attributes itself. The `reverse` need to be specified only if you have more that one relationship between entities and automatic relationship building is not possible.

If you remove the `reverse` from the entities declarations, it will work just fine:

```
class Pais(db.Entity):
    _table_ = ['SAD', 'TA_PAIS']
    codigo = PrimaryKey(int, column="CD_PAIS")
    nome = Required(str, column="NM_PAIS")
    pessoas = Set(lambda: Pessoa)

class Pessoa(db.Entity):
    _table_ = ['SAD', 'TB_PESSOA']
    identificador = PrimaryKey(int, column="ID_PESSOA")
    nome = Required(str, column="NM_PESSOA")
    tipo_pessoa = Required(str, column="IN_TIPO_PESSOA")
    numero_registro = Optional(str, column="NR_REGISTRO")
    pais = Required(Pais)
```

Here you can find more information about entity relationships: https://docs.ponyorm.com/relationships.html

Also you might want to use the online Entity-Relationship Diagram Editor https://editor.ponyorm.com/. It can help you with data modeling for your application.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when the SQL is generated.

```
File "/home/dev/.pyenv/versions/3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pony/orm/dbapiprovider.py", line 55, in wrap_dbapi_exceptions
    except dbapi_module.DatabaseError as e: raise DatabaseError(e)
pony.orm.dbapiprovider.DatabaseError: ORA-00904: "TB_PESSOA"."PAIS": invalid identifier

SELECT "TB_PESSOA"."ID_PESSOA", "TB_PESSOA"."NM_PESSOA", "TB_PESSOA"."IN_TIPO_PESSOA", "TB_PESSOA"."NR_REGISTRO", "TB_PESSOA"."PAIS"
FROM "SAD"."TB_PESSOA" "TB_PESSOA"
WHERE 0 = 1
```

The PAIS does not exist in TB_PESSOA in fact, it is a field called CD_PAIS that is a foreign key into TA_PAIS.